# Every breakpoint can alter the Database except POST?

Tags: asp.net, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, backend

so I'm really new in the world of backend development and i happened to stumble upon a really good junior .net position but the only problem was i have only prior experience in embedded software development using C and Assembly with ARM proccesors so this question might really be noobish but I've been banging my head against the wall for far too long trying to figure out what's wrong and i cant get to a answer.

Let me tell you about the problem, So my task is to make a service that will take a .gml file and then parse it and save it to a database and alongside that there should be those classic delete put and get endpoints, since one gml feature can have multiple coordinates there is a one to many relation established between those 2 tables in the database, alongside all of that there is a datetime mamber that is used for tracking history but it's not important for now.

The problem I'm having is that everything works(delete and get(and variations of get)) but post seems to be acting up, i get a response code 200 telling me that the object was succesfully created and that everything was ok, then when i open postgresql and refresh nothing is there, meanwhile if a manually enter data in the database i can get the data and delete it with no problem, I've been debbuging the code trying to see where does it break but even when debugging everything seems fine.

The approach im taking in developing this is ASP .NET with entity framework doing code first to create the database in postgresql.

here is the link to the repo if anyone can take a look and help:
https://github.com/baddotnetdev/help

the data Im using to test the post methos is this string:

"<Feature fid="142" featureType="school" Description="A middle school"> <Polygon name="extent" srsName="epsg:27354"> <LineString name="extent" srsName="epsg:27354">  491888.999999459,5458045.99963358 491904.999999458,5458044.99963358 491908.999999462,5458064.99963358 491924.999999461,5458064.99963358 491925.999999462,5458079.99963359 491977.999999466,5458120.9996336 491953.999999466,5458017.99963357    "

Practically everything from refactoring my code, changing the order by which my objects are saved at, debbuging the code, doing the latest migration before everything to be sure that the data type is ok and a lot more, I myself am not even sure what i did anymore, this whole thing just became brain salad in my head and i dont think i can figure this out on my own.

Comment: Narrow the issue using debugging - put a breakpoint in your POST code. If the string argument is correct then for some reason saving doesn't work. If the string is not there, there's also nothing to save. I bet on the latter. Without narrowing the issue, your question is unintentionally too complex, involving both the web stack and the database but only part of this setup fails.

Comment: I did debug specifically the code in the POST endpoint when i sent the string over swagger and there was no indication that anything was wrong. the string is passed to the method, then i'ts parsed and an object is succesfully created(the object is the kind of object that is expected from the db) and then it's saved succesfully(or so it seems from the side of visual studio).

Comment: You are not throwing your errors from the _dbhelper so that is why you get "success" even when / if there are failures.

Comment: I will add that in the _dbhelper class and see what I get, thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

This is your code where you save features:

```cs
 public void SaveGmlFeature(GmlFeatureModel featureModel) 
        {
            try {
                GmlFeature dbTable = new GmlFeature();
                if (featureModel.Id > 0)
                {
                    dbTable = _context.GmlFeatures.Where(d => d.Id.Equals(featureModel.Id)).FirstOrDefault() ?? new GmlFeature();
                    if (dbTable != null)
                    {
                        // PUT (ka update ali ne znan sta bi updatea pa san samo navea random parametre)
                        // update jedino koordinata zajedno sa nekin last modified parametron koja je lista datuma
                        dbTable.FeatureType = featureModel.FeatureType;
                        dbTable.Description = featureModel.Description;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // POST

                        GmlFeature NewEntry = new GmlFeature();

                        NewEntry.Id = featureModel.Id;
                        NewEntry.FeatureType = featureModel.FeatureType;
                        NewEntry.Description = featureModel.Description;
                        NewEntry.Coordinates = featureModel.Coordinates;
                        _context.GmlFeatures.Add(NewEntry);

                    }
                    _context.SaveChangesAsync();


                }
                

            }
                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Exception innerException = ex.InnerException;
                // Log or handle the inner exception accordingly
            }
            
        }
```

Consider this line:

```cs
dbTable = _context.GmlFeatures
    .Where(d => d.Id.Equals(featureModel.Id))
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? new GmlFeature();
```

if the feature exists in the db it is set to that entity. But if it does not, you are setting it to a new GmlFeature. So in the next line, **dbTable is never null**.

So your code that you want to execute to insert new entities is actually dead code. I guess you would actually have some kind of an update occurring (perhaps on some entity such as id #1 or #2 ... not sure) but anyway this would explain not saving the new entity as expected.

I think you could fix that by not assigning a default entity in that line:

```cs
dbTable = _context.GmlFeatures
.Where(d => d.Id.Equals(featureModel.Id))
.FirstOrDefault(); // ?? new GmlFeature
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response to my question, yeah now i see that there is dead code checking if the dbTable object is null and it will never be, the line of code was previously written just like you wrote it there without adding a default value and it didn't work :(. Thank you anywayfor the help :).

Comment: actually wait, i will try it again since i remembered there were more changes to the code in the meantime

Comment: Still no luck :(.

Comment: when i go line by line with the debugger it returns nothing suspiscious when adding a row to the database and then saving changes

Comment: you are not awaiting an async method ... I'm confused. That looks wrong. `_context.SaveChangesAsync()`

Comment: That was something that a friend suggested since _context.SaveChanges() wasn't working, accidentally left that in.